# Is Microsoft SQL Server 2012 required to make an Entity Framework Model First database in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: sql-server

This might be a stupid question. But I have to be sure because I have major problem setting up a simple database in VS2013 using Entity Framework Model First.

I'm trying to complete this tutorial step by step: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj205424

I got stuck at step 3 - Generating the database, and I got this error message when I tried to enter the Server Name:

[image]

I really need to know this because right now I can't even get into SQL Server Management Studio without getting the Errormessage "Please reinstall the application". When I installed Sql Server 2012, My OS was Windows 8 and then it worked just fine with windows authentication. But when I upgraded to windows 8.1, this problem occured. I don't know if this is relevant or not...

So, is SQL Server 2012 really needed to make an ASP.NET MVC 5 project in VS2013 with a database solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not needed, as both VS2012 and 13 comes with the smallest db integrated (localdb). Although you have to make sure it's set up and running:

```
sqllocaldb start v11.0
```

Use the localdb in your application:

```
(localdb)\v11.0
```

Then you can check its status with a command `sqllocaldb info`. After the configured in your application, you can manage it through VS2013 - SQL Server Database tab.

Comment: Thanks, but where in VS 2013 do I inserts those commands? I entered thos commands in the package manager console.

Comment: You insert them in system's command line - sqllocaldb cmd should be available, or find sqllocaldb.exe in VisualStudio directory and execute the command from this place.

Comment: I made progress. Looks like it's working now.

Thanks!